# How to test my Vue website in different views in real devices before put it online?

Tags: mysql, node.js, vue.js, express

Currently I am working on a website that uses **Vue-js** as front-end technology and **Node + MySQL** as the back-end part. In the development mode, when I am connecting to the internet and use `npm run serve` (I am using Vue version 2) I see these lines in my command-line:

[image: command-line image]

That is very good feature of **Vue-CLI** that helps me to see and test my website in for example my mobile device (with the help of address in the **Network** part of above image). But unfortunately when I go to some pages (like "article pages") that have some information from **back-end** part of site, I could not see them in my mobile. The reason is clear. I use Node server in other terminal in my laptop and also run **XAMPP** to have **MySQL** database and both of them are not related to **Vue-CLI**. So their part of information could not be seen in real devices like my mobile phone.

I want to know is there any solution that I could test and see **all** parts of my site **before** putting it online and in real device? I know that I could use **browser utilities** for testing **responsive design** but I want to see it in a real device. Also when I searches for that, I usually find websites and solutions that works when the site is **online** (not using localhost). If any developer has any idea for that (when using Node as back-end or other languages in **general** in combination with Vue-CLI) that could help me to see my website in real device, I am so curious to understand that. Is there any package that does it for me?

Comment: You can try `ngrok`. Here is the [link](https://ngrok.com/) to it.

Comment: Host it on a platform where you could have some preview environment (usually in pipelines created by pull requests). Then, when properly tested on your own devices  or services like Browserstack, you could merge it into `main` and rollout it to the world. Otherwise, a local tunnel is also feasible indeed. But you could totally achieve a local network via proper configuration of your local IPs. I don't see why it couldn't work.

Comment: @Shreeraj I followed the link you posted. I did the instructions of [get started](https://ngrok.com/docs/getting-started) page. But it did not solve the problem. Again when I see the site in a device (other than my laptop that runs XAMPP), it **does not** show article pages.

Comment: @kissu could you explain me how configure **my local IPs** properly. I do not know anything about that concept. Is it very complicated or by reading some docs I could understand that?

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a home wifi, visit the ip address shown the screenshot you shared "http://192.168.1.50:880" on your mobile device or any other device connected to the same wifi.

Comment: I know that, but the problem is for parts of site that are related to **back-end** (Node + MySQL). That parts could not be seen.

Comment: @hamid-davodi this is what I meant by configure your local IPs. Since there is a server in your network, you can have communication at your place in the same manner between all of your servers. It can even reach out to the external world if needed. You could even port forward (on your router) and have access to your local IP via your external IP. This is not uncommon and requires to set your IPs from one to the other as it could be a classic endpoint let's say. At the end, if your frontend sends a call to `192.168.x.x` or `https://mywebsite.com`, it's pretty much the same thing.